# Anonymous device array in CUDA

Tags: cuda

I would like to initialize device pointer with anonymous array:

```
 __device__ const unsigned int *ff = (const unsigned int[]){90, 50, 100};
```

However it does not work, cause anonymous array is in host memory. Is it possible to initialize device pointer with anonymous array in CUDA?

Comment: This is *identical* to your last question. Why ask the same question again?

Comment: I`ve got the reason of the problem in my last question. Now I am asking if its possible to solve it

Comment: The answer I provided explains precisely why there isn't a solution of the sort you imagine.

Comment: I`ve got it. I would to like to save anonymous array in device memory and put device pointer to it.

Comment: Yeah, that`s what I asked: is it possible? Cause I have array of structures with several member pointers which I need to initialize with array. Solution you provided in last question is quite hard to implement and awkward